# web scraping : getting '\n' tag while scraping data with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table from Wikipedia page
[Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peths_in_Pune).

I am getting error in creating data frame because I am getting /n tag when I separate each column by , to save in csv

Example : row1 output is

',Navi Peth\n,British administration\n,1818+\n,Navi (Marathi: New)\n'

I am not getting why I am getting this \n and how to remove it.
I think as a result of this \n I am getting error in creating dataframe :

Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 2

my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
page1 = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peths_in_Pune').text
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1, 'lxml')
table = soup1.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
#table
table1=""
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    row1=""
    for tds in tr.find_all('td'):
        row1=row1+","+tds.text
    table1=table1+row1[1:]
row1
```

',Navi Peth\n,British administration\n,1818+\n,Navi (Marathi: New)\n'

further :

```
file=open("data1.csv","wb")
file.write(bytes(table1,encoding="ascii"))
df = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', header=None)
df
```

Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 2

**PS :Result I want is first column from the wiki table**

Comment: Another code I tried is :
 links = table.find_all('a')
peth = []
for link in links:
    peth.append(link.get('title'))
#peth

But this gives me list of  col1 and col2 both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single shot, you can do this with `pandas` `read_html` function:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peths_in_Pune")[1]

print(df)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b2c7efa147b5b2694e1c38ca31cce3d8/data.csv)

[image]

For the **First Column**:

```py
target = df['Peth Naam'].to_list()

print(target)
```

Output :

```
['Kasba Peth', 'Guruwar Peth', 'Somwar Peth', 'Mangalwar Peth', 'Shukrawar Peth', 'Raviwar Peth', 'Shaniwar Peth', 'Bhavani Peth', 'Ghorpade Peth', 'Budhwar Peth', 'Ganesh Peth', 'Sadashiv Peth', 'Narayan Peth', 'Rasta Peth', 'Nana Peth', 'Ganj Peth(later renamed to Mahatma Phule Peth)', 'Navi Peth']
```

Now back to the real issue:

use `item.get_text("\n", strip=True)`

Answer (score -1):

Just a simpler version to get the required table in a df with pandas read_html method

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peths_in_Pune")[1]

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: where the answer for the main issue then ? your answer is using just a different solution. but it doesn't fix the main `issue`. consider telling the `OP` a solution for his main issue before offering a different solution.

Comment: Thanks. that's the simplest way. and I was struggling with bs4

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη sure will keep that in mind thank you for the suggestion ..

Comment: @Apurv happy to help :)